# Windows Installer Cleanup Utility retired, alternative?

Tags: windows-7, cleaning, windows-installer

So the Windows\installer folder (and the WinSxS folder, but that's another story) is eating up quite a LOT of space on my hdd. Windows Installer Cleanup utility was the tool of the trade before, but now Microsoft zapped it with the reason that it's insecure and might delete something that shouldn't be deleted.

So my question is: If I shouldn't use this tool to try freeing some space, what else? My Windows directory is, alone, using like 25 gb. Most of it comes to the installer and winsxs folder.

Answer (score 1):

Priform's [CCLeaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) is a popular choice for removing tempoary files, unistalling programes and generally tidying up. Free for non-bussiness use, supports Windows 7, Vista, XP, 2000 and both 32 and 64-bit flavours.

Comment: This covers general cleaning of a Windows installation. The windows installer cleanup is quite specific though :). Also I'd have refered to all the other questions regarding Windows cleanup then.

Comment: CCleaner also allows removal of uninstallers and caches for installed updates, which can be a significant chunck of disk space if you've never cleaned them before.

Answer (score 1):

Try [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/) This application is similar to [ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner), it frees cache, deletes cookies, clears Internet history, shreds temporary files, deletes logs, and discards junk.

Use BleachBit to:

- Free disk space
- Reduce the size of backups and the time to create them by removing unnecessary files  -
- Maintain privacy Improve system performance
- Clear applications cache

BleachBit includes a growing list of cleaners. Typically each cleaner represents an application such as Firefox or Internet Explorer. Within each cleaner, BleachBit gives options covering components that can be cleaned such as cache, cookies, and log files.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to include a bit of info about what the software is and how it solves the problem? Just including a link is not very helpful.

Comment: Also info on how it relates to my problem. I got ccleaner. But does BleachBit also clean the Windows Installer Cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [revo uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html). I don't know how good the free version is though.

Comment: I don't actually want to delete programs. I just want to clean the Windows installer CACHE. I know that uninstalling programs would also make the cache smaller ;), but this is not what I am asking for... EDIT: Holy crap it does try finding artifacts of not completely uninstalled programs. I'll try it out!

Comment: I think the "Junk Files Cleaner" option might do what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I am testing it now!

Answer (score 0):

> **Note for the SU community:**
> I came across this question while researching how to free up disk space on a Windows installation, as I had a similar problem as OP and I couldn't remember the name of the built-in Windows tool I was looking for.
> Turns out I eventually found it again...
> I'm adding this piece of information as it could result in other temporary files being deleted, which could assist in freeing up disk space on a Windows installation.

---

*Fast forward 2023*

You could try using the built-in **Disk Cleanup** utility from Microsoft.

> To delete temporary files:
>
> 1. In the search box on the taskbar, type disk cleanup, and select Disk Cleanup from the list of results.
> 2. Select the drive you want to clean up, and then select OK.
> 3. Under Files to delete, select the file types to get rid of. To get a description of the file type, select it.
> 4. Select OK.
>
> If you need to free up more space, you can also delete system files:
>
> 1. In Disk Cleanup, select Clean up system files.
> 2. Select the file types to get rid of. To get a description of the file type, select it.
> 3. Select OK.

<sup>***Reference:** [Disk cleanup in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/disk-cleanup-in-windows-8a96ff42-5751-39ad-23d6-434b4d5b9a68) (Microsoft | Support)*</sup>

It doesn't do a fantastic job, but it can remove some old temporary files, including old  Windows Installation(s) / (media) found in either the `$WINDOWS.~BT` or `$WINDOWS.~WS` directories.

Comment: thanks for a belated but helpful answer. disk cleanup is my usual go-to too, and microsoft actually has some guides on how to do sxs cleanup nowadays

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11

Answer (score 0):

So nowadays there is actually another way to do a specific cleanup on the sxs folder, as detailed [on this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11)

I'm gonna pull a few quotes from the page, as it explains it very well:

> Don't delete the WinSxS folder, you can instead reduce the size of the WinSxS folder using tools built into Windows. For more information about the WinSxS folder, see Manage the Component Store.
> The operating system automatically reduces the size of the WinSxS folder by using methods similar to the ones described in this topic. Windows also uses internal processes to reduce the size of the WinSxS folder, such as uninstalling and deleting packages with components that have been replaced by other components with newer versions. Previous versions of some components are kept on the system for a period of time, allowing you to rollback if necessary. After a period of time, these older components are automatically removed from the installation.

The ways detailed on the page are like this:

- Run the StartComponentCleanup task in Task Scheduler to clean up and compress components

  Run `schtasks.exe /Run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Servicing\StartComponentCleanup"`
- Using DISM, runs the same process but without the "scheduled tasks" roundabout way

  Run `Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`
- Using DISM, add the /ResetBase switch

  Using the /ResetBase parameter together with the /StartComponentCleanup parameter of DISM.exe on a running version of Windows 10 or later removes all superseded versions of every component in the component store.

  Run `Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase`